# How to get rid of the passphrase prompt in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10, bitbucket, visual-studio-2019

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise OS, every time when I try to push or pull changes to/from the remote bitbucket repo in VS 2019, I get the following prompt.

[image]

How to get rid of this prompt once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are being asked a password to access your SSH key.

When you generate a private key, you usually get asked whether you want to protect it with a password or not. If you do, you will be asked for it every time you need to access it.

If you are annoyed by the need of using the password on a regular basis, I'd suggest re-generating the key from scratch, without password, and maybe thinking of other ways of protecting your data, such as disk encryption.

See [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/what-benefit-is-there-to-adding-a-password-to-your-ssh-key) for a discussion on the benefits of protecting your key with a password.